# Yii Framework Update page add more models to view

Tags: php, yii, one-to-many

I have a update form which cant be loaded because it cant find the models.. I have three tables.. Movie, YoutubeVideos, Twitter. Movie has a one to many relationship with the other tables.. I want to able to create the update form using the current movie id and match with the data in youtube videos and twitter. and show results..

This is what i have so

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{



    $model=$this->loadModel($id);

    // $modelYoutubeVideo = YoutubeVideo::model()->findByAttributes(array('movie_id'=>$id));
    // $modelTwitterFeed = TwitterFeed::model()->findByAttributes(array('movie_id'=>$id));

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Movie']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Movie'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'modelYoutubeVideo'=> YoutubeVideo::model()->findByAttributes(array('movie_id'=>$model->id)),
        'modelTwitterFeed'=> TwitterFeed::model()->findByAttributes(array('movie_id'=>$id))

    ));
}
```

Movie Model --

```
<?php
```

/**
 * This is the model class for table "movie".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'movie':
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $movie_name
 * @property integer $studio_id
 * @property integer $country_id
 * @property integer $movie_rating_id
 * @property integer $map_pin_id
 * @property string $description
 * @property string $title_image
 * @property string $title_trailer_youtube_code
 * @property string $release_date
 * @property string $bg_colour_code
 * @property string $text_colour_code
 * @property integer $is_released
 * @property integer $is_advanced_booking_allowed
 * @property string $advanced_booking_start_date
 * @property string $advanced_booking_end_date
 * @property string $domain_prefix
 * @property string $facebook_app_id
 * @property string $facebook_app_url
 * @property string $facebook_icon_image_url
 * @property string $facebook_text
 * @property string $twitter_text
 * @property string $booking_share_text
 * @property string $westworld_movie_id
 * @property string $home_tracking_url
 * @property string $shows_tracking_url
 *
 * The followings are the available model relations:
 * @property Competition[] $competitions
 * @property Studio $studio
 * @property Country $country
 * @property MovieRating $movieRating
 * @property MapPin $mapPin
 * @property TwitterFeed[] $twitterFeeds
 * @property YoutubeVideo[] $youtubeVideos
 */
class Movie extends CActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'movie';
    }

```
/**
 * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
 */
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('studio_id, country_id, movie_rating_id, map_pin_id, is_released, is_advanced_booking_allowed', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('movie_name domain_prefix, facebook_app_url, facebook_icon_image_url, home_tracking_url, shows_tracking_url', 'length', 'max'=>255),
        array('title_image', 'file','types'=>'jpg, gif, png', 'allowEmpty'=>true, 'on'=>'update'),
        array('title_trailer_youtube_code', 'length', 'max'=>50),
        array('bg_colour_code, text_colour_code', 'length', 'max'=>8),
        array('facebook_app_id', 'length', 'max'=>20),
        array('westworld_movie_id', 'length', 'max'=>10),
        array('title_image', 'file', 'allowEmpty'=>true),
        array('description, release_date, advanced_booking_start_date, advanced_booking_end_date, facebook_text, twitter_text, booking_share_text', 'safe'),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('id, movie_name, studio_id, country_id, movie_rating_id, map_pin_id, description, title_trailer_youtube_code, release_date, bg_colour_code, text_colour_code, is_released, is_advanced_booking_allowed, advanced_booking_start_date, advanced_booking_end_date, domain_prefix, facebook_app_id, facebook_app_url, facebook_icon_image_url, facebook_text, twitter_text, booking_share_text, westworld_movie_id, home_tracking_url, shows_tracking_url', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}

/**
 * @return array relational rules.
 */
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'competitions' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Competition', 'movie_id'),
        'studio' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Studio', 'studio_id'),
        'country' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Country', 'country_id'),
        'movieRating' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'MovieRating', 'movie_rating_id'),
        'mapPin' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'MapPin', 'map_pin_id'),
        'twitterFeeds' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'TwitterFeed', 'movie_id'),
        'YoutubeVideo' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'YoutubeVideo', 'movie_id'),
    );
}

/**
 * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'id' => 'ID',
        'movie_name' => 'Movie Name',
        'studio_id' => 'Studio',
        'country_id' => 'Country',
        'movie_rating_id' => 'Movie Rating',
        'map_pin_id' => 'Map Pin',
        'description' => 'Description',
        'title_image' => 'Title Image',
        'title_trailer_youtube_code' => 'Title Trailer Youtube Code',
        'release_date' => 'Release Date',
        'bg_colour_code' => 'Bg Colour Code',
        'text_colour_code' => 'Text Colour Code',
        'is_released' => 'Is Released',
        'is_advanced_booking_allowed' => 'Is Advanced Booking Allowed',
        'advanced_booking_start_date' => 'Advanced Booking Start Date',
        'advanced_booking_end_date' => 'Advanced Booking End Date',
        'domain_prefix' => 'Domain Prefix',
        'facebook_app_id' => 'Facebook App',
        'facebook_app_url' => 'Facebook App Url',
        'facebook_icon_image_url' => 'Facebook Icon Image Url',
        'facebook_text' => 'Facebook Text',
        'twitter_text' => 'Twitter Text',
        'booking_share_text' => 'Booking Share Text',
        'westworld_movie_id' => 'Westworld Movie',
        'home_tracking_url' => 'Home Tracking Url',
        'shows_tracking_url' => 'Shows Tracking Url',
    );
}

/**
 * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
 *
 * Typical usecase:
 * - Initialize the model fields with values from filter form.
 * - Execute this method to get CActiveDataProvider instance which will filter
 * models according to data in model fields.
 * - Pass data provider to CGridView, CListView or any similar widget.
 *
 * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models
 * based on the search/filter conditions.
 */
public function search()
{
    // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('country_id', Yii::app()->user->getState('country_id'));


    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    $criteria->compare('movie_name',$this->movie_name,true);
    $criteria->compare('studio_id',$this->studio_id);
    $criteria->compare('country_id',$this->country_id);
    $criteria->compare('movie_rating_id',$this->movie_rating_id);
    $criteria->compare('map_pin_id',$this->map_pin_id);
    $criteria->compare('description',$this->description,true);
    $criteria->compare('title_image',$this->title_image,true);
    $criteria->compare('title_trailer_youtube_code',$this->title_trailer_youtube_code,true);
    $criteria->compare('release_date',$this->release_date,true);
    $criteria->compare('bg_colour_code',$this->bg_colour_code,true);
    $criteria->compare('text_colour_code',$this->text_colour_code,true);
    $criteria->compare('is_released',$this->is_released);
    $criteria->compare('is_advanced_booking_allowed',$this->is_advanced_booking_allowed);
    $criteria->compare('advanced_booking_start_date',$this->advanced_booking_start_date,true);
    $criteria->compare('advanced_booking_end_date',$this->advanced_booking_end_date,true);
    $criteria->compare('domain_prefix',$this->domain_prefix,true);
    $criteria->compare('facebook_app_id',$this->facebook_app_id,true);
    $criteria->compare('facebook_app_url',$this->facebook_app_url,true);
    $criteria->compare('facebook_icon_image_url',$this->facebook_icon_image_url,true);
    $criteria->compare('facebook_text',$this->facebook_text,true);
    $criteria->compare('twitter_text',$this->twitter_text,true);
    $criteria->compare('booking_share_text',$this->booking_share_text,true);
    $criteria->compare('westworld_movie_id',$this->westworld_movie_id,true);
    $criteria->compare('home_tracking_url',$this->home_tracking_url,true);
    $criteria->compare('shows_tracking_url',$this->shows_tracking_url,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}

/**
 * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
 * Please note that you should have this exact method in all your CActiveRecord descendants!
 * @param string $className active record class name.
 * @return Movie the static model class
 */
public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}

public function getYesNoOptions(){
    $optionList = array();
    $optionList[0] = "No";
    $optionList[1] = "Yes";
    return $optionList;
}

public function getRatingOptions(){
    $ratingList = MovieRating::model()->findAll();
    $optionList = CHtml::listData($ratingList, 'id', 'rating_name');
    return $optionList;
}

public function getStudioOptions(){
    $studioList = Studio::model()->findAll();
    $optionList = CHtml::listData($studioList, 'id', 'name');
    return $optionList;
}

public function getMapPinOptions(){
    $mapPinList = MapPin::model()->findAll();
    $optionList = CHtml::listData($mapPinList, 'id', 'pin_colour_code');
    return $optionList;
}
```

}

RETRY - Think it needs to be along these lines

```
public function loadYoutubeVideoModel($id)
{

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->addSearchCondition('movie_id', $id);

    $model=YoutubeVideo::model()->findAll($criteria);

    if($model===null)
        throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
    return $model;
}

public function loadTwitterModel($id)
{
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->addSearchCondition('movie_id', $id);

    $model=TwitterFeed::model()->findAll($criteria);

    if($model===null)
        throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
    return $model;
}
```

Comment: "I have a update form which cant be loaded because it cant find the models." is it showing some error? post that error and view code

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public function actionUpdate($id){



$model=Movie::model()->with('YoutubeVideo','twitterFeeds')->findbypk($id);

// $modelYoutubeVideo = YoutubeVideo::model()->findByAttributes(array('movie_id'=>$id));
// $modelTwitterFeed = TwitterFeed::model()->findByAttributes(array('movie_id'=>$id));

// Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
// $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

if(isset($_POST['Movie']))
{
    $model->attributes=$_POST['Movie'];
    if($model->save())
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
}

$this->render('update',array(
    'model'=>$model,
)

);
```

}

You can show your datas in update view file (not in _form file) with this code.

```
foreach($modelYoutubeVideo as $youtube){
   echo $youtube["blabla"];
}
foreach($modelTwitterFeed as $twitter){
   echo $twitter["blabla"];
}
```

Comment: thanks the reply, i already have this in the loadmodel function, my problem is using that id to get the other data from the other models

Comment: Added Ive tried this with no result  public function loadYoutubeVideoModel($id)
 {

  $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
  $criteria->condition='movie_id=:movie_id';
  $criteria->params=array(':movie_id'=>10);

  $model=YoutubeVideo::model()->find($criteria);

  if($model===null)
   throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
  return $model;
 }

Comment: Pls fix your post for movie model

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: Yep it didnt work the two new functions ive put.. work now but i get this error think its coz my form cant load the array of data from the one to many call... Array to string conversion

Comment: try echo the data in foreach loop

Comment: sorry any way you could please write me and example.. really new to php thanks